# What is the difference between C# Attribute and C# Static Field?

Tags: c#, attributes, field

According to Microsoft documents,

> Attributes provide a powerful method of associating metadata, or declarative information, with code.

> The static member is callable on a class even when no instance of the class has been created. The static member is always accessed by the class name, not the instance name.

But according to my understanding, both of the Attribute and Static Field are

1. Can be accessed at runtime
2. Bind with class, not object.

So what are the difference between them?

Comment: You'r right, they have a few similarities. But that doesn't make it same, they are far from each other. It's like comparing glass and laptop because both are hard and can be damaged. 

Maybe just wirte what is your use case and then we can give you some pros and cons of both

Comment: I am learning C#, and I am from C++. So I feel confuses about what Attribute can do that static filed cannot.

Comment: A field (static or otherwise) is a runtime variable. An attribute is a class whose instances can be attached to other classes at compile time.

Comment: purpose of attribute is to decorate class, method, property or field, you can attach them to any class and use in many ways, e.g to say how to validate property, to add some human friendly description that will be displayed when calling .ToString(), you can decorate method argument that it's `CallerMemberName` and it will assign your caller member name as a value of argument, you cannot do most of these things with static fields. You will use static fields mostly to declare some constants

Comment: @YongdaFan one of the most common usecases for  attributes is serialization - for example in popular [Newtonsoft Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm) package they can be used to describe how class should be serialized/deserialized. The same approach can be seen in many other libraries, including built in ones.

Comment: Attributes are not meant to be changed at runtime; they are primarily to tell the compiler things about your class. Static fields are just variables that are unique in a class and contain data common to all instances or even for other code outside the class. - You really should approach the question with a couple of use cases!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DEFINITION**

A static data field or property is a variable *encapsulated* in the *abstraction* of a class definition.

Attribute is a *decoration*, a *parameter*, not a data itself, added to a class type or to a member field, property or method.

An attribute itself does nothing and represent nothing in terms of data or code : it is a conceptual artifact, added to the code, that can be used by the code, by some method, to change the behavior.

Attribute is a class that can contains data and methods to manage some behaviors of a class.

Attributes allows to segregate more between abstraction and encapsulation.

They allow to better refine design as well as to specialize behaviors at coding time while allowing generalization.

**EXAMPLE**

Consider this class:

```
public class LogFile
{
  static public List<LogFile> LogFiles { get; private set; }
}
```

Here it is a static list that contains all log files instantiated.

It is a data, a variable, something concrete and tangible, directly usable by internal and external code.

Here is an example of attribute usage:

```
[LogFileStorage(LogFilePath.User)]
public class LogFile
{
}
```

Here it is a code tag added to the class definition at the code level, that can't be changed, unless using reflexion, and that can be used by the logfile manager class to define a save path like in a temp folder or the user app folder or a runtime defined path (in a different and detached way from a constant or a default value).

So in this example, the log file save method will check the class attributes to know where to save it.

An attribute lets coders to parameterize class they define as well as child class and any class member.

A classical example is the Serializable attribute:

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute

**TUTORIALS**

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_attributes.htm

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/attributes

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_encapsulation.htm

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mkagrahari/introduction-to-object-oriented-programming-concepts-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: I think I understand the differences. Thanks for the great explanation.